# Does Flickr allow shared albums with pictures from multiple people? What's the best service for this?

Tags: service-recommendation, flickr, sharing

My friends and I took a bunch of pictures (and videos) on a three week trip overseas. We're not professionals or anything, but we amassed more than 2000 vacation photos from six sources (smartphones, a DSLR, a GoPro, and a point-and-shoot).

Is there some service that will allow us to upload all these photos and put them into a combined album? Does Flickr have shared albums?

We were using Google Photos, but they have a 2000 photo limit on shared albums. Their interface is also annoying sometimes. When showing photos to family one-by-one in full-screen mode, photos often show up in extremely low resolution unless you click out and click back in.

We also have a bunch of accidental, blurry, or nearly-identical photos that we want to delete. And just generally clean things up and organize, like a selection of the best photos.

Is there a service that works well for what we want?

Answer (score 6):

> Is there some service that will allow us to upload all these photos and put them into a combined album? Does Flickr have shared albums?

Flickr does not have shared albums, but instead has a feature called **groups**. If each of you get an individual Flickr account, one of you can create a group (public, invitation only public, or private, up to you), and invite all the other folks to become members of the group who can submit photos into the group pool.

> We also have a bunch of accidental, blurry, or nearly-identical photos that we want to delete. And just generally clean things up and organize, like a selection of the best photos.

While it would probably be best to do this editing prior to uploading :), if you choose to upload all your photos, you will be selecting which photos to submit to the pool, so you can leave out the ones you prefer not to have in the group. Also, whoever chooses to be an administrator of the group can edit what appears in the pool.

See: [Flickr's creating a group page](https://www.flickr.com/groups_create.gne).

Comment: In addition, you can also create galleries (https://www.flickr.com/photos/lukeharby/galleries/72157622493538640/ for example). This is not then reliant on users having to submit images to a group, they can be curated by you.

Comment: @lharby, galleries, however, do not allow you to add your _own_ images, and is limited to 50 images. Don't think that fulfills the OP's needs.

Answer (score 0):

Digital cameras make it really easy to take huge numbers of pictures, but you do need to be selective about which to share. 2,000 photos is a lot, way too many to view in one sitting, for example. I would select 200 or so and upload just those to Google Photos.

You could also try Dropbox, which has a rudimentary photo gallery function.